# pass c structs (from c++ to Python) through boost python get_override method

Tags: python, c++, boost, struct

I've created a python 3 wrapper for a pure virtual C++ function using boost python.

I'm using get_override method to call my python wrapper as shown:

`override f = this->get_override("handleMsg");`

I can use the `override f` object to send primitive arguments to my python wrapper, for example:

```
f(10,20);//this works

int tmp =10;
f(10,20); //this works
```

My python method is simply printing an acknowledgement using print().

However, **I need to pass either a cpp struct, or a shared_ptr to my python method.**

If I try to send these, my python script crashes without any stack trace in gdb.

**How can I send a cpp struct, pointer or boost shared_ptr to my python wrapper ?**

I've tried numerous implementations described here, but none have worked.

I'm using Boost 1.48 and Python 3

Comment: as of now, I'm recreating a boost::python::object every time I receive a cpp object. Is there a more direct approach ?